# Does Outlook autoarchive delete sent messages?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, pst

I am running Outlook Professional 2010 with an exchange account. I archived old items, thinking it was a local operation, only to find that the emails were removed from the server too! Now I am checking the .pst file from my pc. The email in the inbox seem to be there, but I cannot find the sent items (and I am interested mostly in the attachments).

[image: bar]

Have they been deleted? In the cleanup setting I don't see anything about deleting.

[image: autoarchive]

Comment: AutoArchive **moves** messages and other outlook items from the server to a PST file. This includes sent items and items in any folders created on the server. The process will move items from folders in the mailbox on the server to identical folders in the PST. So messages in the sent items on the server will be in the sent items folder on the PST

Comment: I did open data file, found the archive, and now I see the inbox under "archives", but no sent items (or drafts, which I don't care). In the archives I only have Deleted Items (empty, no big deal), inbox, search folders

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of your auto archive settings in the question?

Comment: @slayernoah updated

Comment: Unless company policy prohibits, you can set Outlook to either store folders and files on the server or in a local PST file. See http://blogs.technet.com/b/seanearp/archive/2010/01/24/creating-a-pst-in-outlook-2010.aspx. This is not of immediate use, but could help prevent that issue in the future.

Comment: At the end I found it, it was archived on another computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Auto-archive works by FOLDER so you should check that the sent items folder has the expected archive settings. That should also show you whether your service owner has disabled archiving.

You should also be VERY careful with archive PST files. They are a constant source of data loss. Don't put them on a networked drive, keep them small and keep them closed as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Like they said autoarchive don't delete sent messages unless you check the box "delete permanently". I suggest try to view your hidden folder. It might be there.